# Autoencoder anamoly detection

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, anomaly-detection

I recently  learnt about the anamoly detection using  autoencoders(specifically denoisinng autoencoders).To train the autoencoders do we need  a data  having some pattern? or is there some way to train in abnormal data ?Also how we decide that the data is suitable for training autoencoder model.

Comment: Alternatively you could use something like Isolation Forest which allows you to include anomalous data in training. Check out [sklearn's implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) and the `contamination` parameter.

Comment: I think the variational autencoder is superior to the denoising autoencoder, specifically in the ability to generate new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need normal data to train on. If you have abnormal instances also, those should be excluded from the training set. Having access to labeled abnormal/normal data is very useful for the validation and testset.
Anything that differs from the normal data (as learned by the autoencoder) is considered an anomaly.

If you have a lot of labeled abnormal and normal data, then you can consider using binary classification instead.